# C# Завершение консольного приложения по таймеру

Tags: c#, многопоточность, таймер

Доброго времени суток.

Прошу помочь разобраться в решении следующей проблемы.

Есть консольное приложение в нём нужно реализовать действия по таймеру.

***Логика действий следующая:***
При старте приложения запускается таймер с интервалом в 1 час.
Пока работает таймер, в параллель с ним работает цикл на проверку запущенного процесса. Если процесс за этот час не был завершен, то приложение закрывается, а если процесс завершился, то таймер останавливается и запускается последовательность действий.

В данный момент я реализовала следующее:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Timer t = new Timer(ComputeBoundOp, 1, 0, 1000);
    Thread.Sleep(100000);
    t.Dispose();

    while (true)
    {
        var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("ProcessName");
        if (processes.Length > 0)
            processes[0].WaitForExit();
        else
            break;
    }

    //Последовательность других действий.

}

private static void ComputeBoundOp(Object state)
{
    Console.WriteLine("In ComputeBoundOp: state={0}", state);
    Thread.Sleep(10000); 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private static void WaitProcess(string processName)
{
    while (true)
    {
        var process = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName).FirstOrDefault();
        if (process == null) break;
        process.WaitForExit();
    }
}

public static void Test()
{
    var ok = Task
        .Run(() => WaitProcess("chrome"))
        .Wait(TimeSpan.FromHours(1));

    if (ok)
    {
        //Последовательность других действий.
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (ok)` это точно сработает?

Comment: @tym32167 что вас смущает ? условие выполнится только если функция проверки процесс(а\ов) успеет завершиться. Вроде бы условия были соблюдены. Cтоит, конечно, еще прикрутить CancellationToken для завершения задачи.

Comment: Сорри, сплю. Увидел Task.Run, но не заметил Wait :)

Comment: @morphey83 Добрый день. Большое спасибо за помощь!!